# Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'. failed to install on any devices

Tags: react-native

when installing the application(ReactNative) with mi device following error getting every time 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> Failed to install on any devices.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.402 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: do you have a device connected to your pc with usb debugging enabled and have you run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: yes i did that one.. and also enabled usb debugging  and also disabled the miui optimization

Comment: try building the app through android studio it will provide a more clearer error message

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: could you show the complete error please, and try running using --stacktrace

Comment: Skipping device 'a48ed1327d24' for 'app:debug': Unknown API Level
:app:installDebug FAILED FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> Failed to install on any devices. * Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: BUILD FAILED

Total time: 16.64 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: i am trying with the react-native stacktrace also its not working